# jQuery/JavaScript find highest value in table column

Tags: javascript, html-table

Here is my table

```
<table id="aktivita">
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>450</td>
    <td>794</td>
    <td>784</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steve</td>
    <td>145</td>
    <td>794</td>
    <td>789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>2794</td>
    <td>2794</td>
    <td>79</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I get each column since the second (after the names) and set the highest value class high, the lowest value class low? 
If more td have same value and is highest (or lowest) all must have proper class.

```
$('#aktivita tr').each(function(){
  var first = $(this).find("td:nth-of-type(2)").text();
  var second = $(this).find("td:nth-of-type(3)").text();
  var third = $(this).find("td:nth-of-type(4)").text();


  console.log(first);
  console.log(second);
  console.log(third);
});
```

This is what I have yet. I don't like much that im using for variables basicly same code. Is there a way how to make it dry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over `td`s and find min and max and process accordingly

```js
$(function(){
  var cols = []
  var trs = $('#aktivita tr')
  var data =$.each(trs , function(index, tr){
    $.each($(tr).find("td").not(":first"), function(index, td){
      cols[index] = cols[index] || [];
      cols[index].push($(td).text())
    })
  });
  cols.forEach(function(col, index){
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, col);
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, col)
    $('#aktivita tr').find('td:eq('+(index+1)+')').each(function(i, td){
      $(td).toggleClass('max', +$(td).text() === max)
      $(td).toggleClass('min', +$(td).text() === min)  
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.max {
  color: blue
}

.min {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="aktivita">
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>450</td>
    <td>794</td>
    <td>784</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steve</td>
    <td>145</td>
    <td>794</td>
    <td>789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>2794</td>
    <td>2794</td>
    <td>79</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is for rows, not columns.

Comment: @Ostrov I guess then I don't understand the question. You wish to highlight the cell with Max and Min value. Right?

Comment: Sorry :) Yes i wish. But for each column, see the screenshot http://imageshack.cz/images/2016/10/18/Beznazvu.png red line means class min, green max.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to work for me:

```
var offset = 1;

$('#aktivita tr').each(function () {
    var values = [];

    $(this).children('td').each(function (i,v) {
        if (i < offset) return;
        var value = parseInt($(this).text());
        if(!isNaN(value))
            values.push(value);
    });

    var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, values);
    var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, values);

    $(this).children('td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == maxValue.toString()) {
            $(this).addClass('max');
        }

        if ($(this).text() == minValue.toString()) {
            $(this).addClass('min');
        }
    });

});
```

Where offset is the number of columns before the actual values start ( just in case you only delivered simplified data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to find min and max value of each `tr` and add classes.

```js
var i = 1;

while (i < $('tr:first-child td').length) {
  var ar = $('table tr').map(function() {
    return Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').text());
  })

  var max = Math.max.apply(null, ar);
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, ar);

  var ar = $('table tr').find('td').each(function() {
    if (Number($(this).text()) == max) {
      $(this).addClass('max');
    } else if (Number($(this).text()) == min) {
      $(this).addClass('min');
    }
  })

  i++;
}
```

```css
.max {
  color: red;
}
.min {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="aktivita">
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>450</td>
    <td>794</td>
    <td>784</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steve</td>
    <td>145</td>
    <td>794</td>
    <td>789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>2794</td>
    <td>2794</td>
    <td>79</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But this highlights the highest/lowest whole column. I would like to get column numbers, find highest/lowest and add class just for this.

Comment: @Ostrov I updated my answer, now it finds min and maximum values for each column.