# jQuery/JavaScript find highest/lowest value in html table column

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How to find the highest/lowest value in an html table is discussed here:
[jQuery/JavaScript find highest value in table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105768/jquery-javascript-find-highest-value-in-table-column/42980260#42980260)

However, my table has more columns, and I want to exclude columns 1 and 2 from being marked. How would I exclude only those two columns from being marked?

Comment: @Pete This is this user's first question. I'm not interested in discouraging them from learning or participating in the web development community by downvoting their first question.

Comment: @Pete Well it wasn't a stupid question, just a little unclear (though not unclear enough for it to be answered...). I thought by upvoting it might help the user earn a little karma/confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very simple. Use the same code snippet from that answer, but make the following change:

```
var data =$.each(trs , function(index, tr){
    $.each($(tr).find("td"), function(index, td){ // Remove .not(":first")
      if (index < 2) return true; // Add this line
      cols[index] = cols[index] || [];
      cols[index].push($(td).text())
    })
});
```

This will skip over the first two columns.

Comment: but, in future, if I want to exclude for example column 1,3,6 ?

Comment: Just alter the `if ()` to check for those indices. The index starts at 0 (so index 0 is column 1), so in that case you could do: `if (index == 0 || index == 2 || index == 5) return true;`

Comment: It works!
thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Please comment here again if you have more questions.

Comment: I noticed this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pete You're right, I've removed the `.not(":first")` from the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have a new problem with this script: 
If I have more tables on the same HTML page, this script have effect only on the first table. How to make it work on all tables wtih specified calss.

Comment: @RomeoAlexandrovich Just put the functionality inside of a function, and select each table: `$('table').each(function() { yourFunction($(this)); });`

Comment: finally I finished script. thanks for help!